# i can't declare a 2 dimentionnal array with sfml Vector2f's data type

Tags: c++, arrays, sfml

i just started on making my first game with sfml and c++ and the issue is as title says
the error shows on the last line where i declare the 2 dimentional array "scene"
it says "this array cannot contain elements of this type"
here's the code :

```
Vector2f playerpos;
Vector2f physicsBasedObjects[] = {Vector2f(0,0),Vector2f(100,-200),playerpos};
Vector2f staticobjects[] = {Vector2f(0,-10),Vector2f(10,-10)};
Vector2f scene[][] = {staticobjects,physicsBasedObjects };
```

Comment: Please include the *exact* error text, not your approximation of it.

Comment: it says "an array" instead of "this array" , my bad , but i just translated it from french to english , it's the massage that shows when i put my mouse over the error

Comment: Please post **the exact error text**, not your approximation of it. Like literally copy and paste the error into an edit of your question. These errors include important contextual information you may not be interpreting correctly.

Comment: If your compiler produces errors in another language that's fine, but it'd help us if you temporarily flipped it to English to debug this issue.

Comment: thank you , i think i kind of understand where the mistake is now !